# Under what conditions does $ \ (a+b)^{n}=a^{n}+b^{n}$ for a natural number $ n \geq 2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Under what conditions does $ \ (a+b)^{n}=a^{n}+b^{n}$ holds for a natural number $ n \geq 2$?

**My attempt at solving:**

Using $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$; if $(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2$, $2ab=0$ therefore $a$ and/or $b$ must be $0$.

If $a$ and/or $b$ is $0$ then $a^2$ and/or $b^2$ will be $0$.

Therefore $(a+b)^2$ can never equal $a^2+b^2$.

Comment: Well if at least one of ${a}$ or ${b}$ is ${0}$, so it's true that ${a^2 + b^2 = (a+b)^2}$ in this instance. The technical details of your proof are fine, it's just your wording I think that seems a bit off, since you essentially solve to find conditions for when ${(a+b)^2 = a^2 + b^2}$ then say it's not possible.

Comment: 1) "Therefore (a+b)2 can never equal a2+b2."  But you *just* said it *could* happen if $a$ or $b$ equal $0$.   If $a=0$ then $(a+b)^2 = b^2 = a^2 + b^2$ and if $b=0$ then $(a+b)^2 = a^2 = a^2 + b^2$.  That's *not* "never".  2) Okay, that's $n = 2$.  What about when $n > 2$ (which is the real heart of the problem).

Comment: The question is to find the condtions where $a^n + b^n= (a+b)^n$.  It *could* happen if $a=0$; it could happen if $b=0$; and it could happen if $a=-b$ and $n$ is odd$.  That's not never. But it is only under special circumstance.  Are there any other cases?

Comment: Just for fun, the equality is called the _freshman's dream_ and is _always_ true in a [Finite Field](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field).

Comment: Well, not “always true.”  For each finite field, it is true for some values of $n.$ More generally, for each field of finite characteristic $p$ and $n=p^k.$ @KlaasvanAarsen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For even $n$ you are right. For odd $n$ we have also $a+b=0$.

Comment: This is true for real answers, $a,b.$ But the lack of effort to show these are the only answers makes me downvote this.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $a\neq0$. Then

$$(a+b)^n=a^n\Big(1+\tfrac{b}{a}\Big)^n$$

Then, to is enough to consider the question for which values $x$ is $(1+x)^n=1+x^n$. For then $(a+b)^n=a^n+b^n$ with $b=ax$.

This leads to finding all the roots of

$$
p_n(x):=\sum^{n-1}_{k=1}\binom{n}{k}x^k=0
$$

When $n=2$, $p_2(x)=2x=0$ and so $x=0$

when $n=3$, $p_3(x)= 3x+3x^2=0$ and so $x=0$ and $x=-1$,

when $n=4$, $p_4(x)=4x+6x^2 + 4 x^3=2x(2+3x+2x^2)=0$ and so, $x=0$, $x=\frac{-3+i\sqrt{7}}{4}$ and $x=\frac{-3-i\sqrt{7}}{4}$.

and so on.

Notice that pairs $(a, b)$ that satisfy $(a+b)^n=a^n+b^n$ may be complex pairs.

Comment: Worth showing, since $a,b$ are not given a specific domain in the question, that the real solutions are easy. When $n$ is even, $x=0$ is the only real solution, and when $n$ odd the real solutions are only $0$ and $-1.$ Solving for complex solutions will be hard, in general.